# How to open the giu window from the menu in the systray tray?

Tags: go, user-interface, imgui

I use the [giu](https://github.com/AllenDang/giu) and [systray](https://github.com/getlantern/systray) packages in Go to create a simple GUI.

And I can't open the window created by giu when I click on the menu item in the tray.

This is how creating a simple tray looks like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
    "time"
)

// Section with tray functions
func startTrayApp() {
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
}

func onReady() {
    systray.SetTitle("test")
    sendItem := systray.AddMenuItem("Send message", "Send message to stdout")
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-sendItem.ClickedCh:
                fmt.Println(time.Now())
            }
        }
    }()
}

func onExit() {
    fmt.Println("Application stopped on " + time.Now().Format("2 Jan 2006 at 15:04:05"))
}

// Main function
func main() {
    startTrayApp()
}
```

As a result, a tray is created and works normally.
[working tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiEw0.png)

I'm adding a function here from the example of creating a giu window:

```golang
// Section with windows creation
func onClickMe() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

func onImSoCute() {
    fmt.Println("Im sooooooo cute!!")
}

func loop() {
    g.SingleWindow().Layout(
        g.Label("Hello world from giu"),
        g.Row(
            g.Button("Click Me").OnClick(onClickMe),
            g.Button("I'm so cute").OnClick(onImSoCute),
        ),
    )
}
```

Now I call only the window from the main function:

```golang
// Main function
func main() {
    wnd := g.NewMasterWindow("Hello world", 400, 200, g.MasterWindowFlagsNotResizable)
    wnd.Run(loop)
}
```

The application also runs:
[running window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU63z.png)

Now I will transfer the window creation call to the tray icon click handler:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    g "github.com/AllenDang/giu"
    "github.com/getlantern/systray"
    "time"
)

// Section with tray functions
func startTrayApp() {
    systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
}

func onReady() {
    systray.SetTitle("test")
    sendItem := systray.AddMenuItem("Send message", "Send message to stdout")
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-sendItem.ClickedCh:
                wnd := g.NewMasterWindow("Hello world", 400, 200, g.MasterWindowFlagsNotResizable)
                wnd.Run(loop)
            }
        }
    }()
}

func onExit() {
    fmt.Println("Application stopped on " + time.Now().Format("2 Jan 2006 at 15:04:05"))
}

// Section with windows creation
func onClickMe() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

func onImSoCute() {
    fmt.Println("Im sooooooo cute!!")
}

func loop() {
    g.SingleWindow().Layout(
        g.Label("Hello world from giu"),
        g.Row(
            g.Button("Click Me").OnClick(onClickMe),
            g.Button("I'm so cute").OnClick(onImSoCute),
        ),
    )
}

// Main function
func main() {
    startTrayApp()
}
```

And when I call this menu item, I get an error related to gorutins:

```
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
SIGABRT: abort
PC=0x198470744 m=3 sigcode=0
signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 50 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x10054f26c, 0x14000190ab8)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x44 fp=0x14000190a40 sp=0x14000190a00 pc=0x10010c114
github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw._Cfunc_glfwCreateWindow(0x190, 0xc8, 0x600003350040, 0x0, 0x0)
        _cgo_gotypes.go:694 +0x34 fp=0x14000190ab0 sp=0x14000190a40 pc=0x1001ef6c4
github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw.CreateWindow.func2(0x190, 0xc8, 0x600003350040, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/zhbert/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw@v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b/window.go:348 +0xf4 fp=0x14000190b50 sp=0x14000190ab0 pc=0x1001f4f84
github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw.CreateWindow(0x190, 0xc8, {0x100595354, 0xb}, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/zhbert/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw@v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b/window.go:348 +0xd8 fp=0x14000190c90 sp=0x14000190b50 pc=0x1001f4ce8
github.com/AllenDang/imgui-go.NewGLFW({0x128018c08}, {0x100595354, 0xb}, 0x190, 0xc8, 0x1)
        /Users/zhbert/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!allen!dang/imgui-go@v1.12.1-0.20221124025851-59b862ca5a0c/PlatformGlfw.go:95 +0x270 fp=0x14000190e50 sp=0x14000190c90 pc=0x10021a490
github.com/AllenDang/giu.NewMasterWindow({0x100595354, 0xb}, 0x190, 0xc8, 0x1)
        /Users/zhbert/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!allen!dang/giu@v0.7.0/MasterWindow.go:69 +0xec fp=0x14000190f80 sp=0x14000190e50 pc=0x1002d596c
main.onReady.func1()
        /Users/zhbert/Programming/gist-for-so-about-giu-and-systray/main.go:22 +0x5c fp=0x14000190fd0 sp=0x14000190f80 pc=0x10030dcfc
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 +0x4 fp=0x14000190fd0 sp=0x14000190fd0 pc=0x1001705d4
created by main.onReady in goroutine 35
        /Users/zhbert/Programming/gist-for-so-about-giu-and-systray/main.go:18 +0xa4

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x10030e3f4, 0x14000155ee8)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/cgocall.go:157 +0x44 fp=0x14000155eb0 sp=0x14000155e70 pc=0x10010c114
github.com/getlantern/systray._Cfunc_nativeLoop()
        _cgo_gotypes.go:127 +0x34 fp=0x14000155ee0 sp=0x14000155eb0 pc=0x10030d354
github.com/getlantern/systray.nativeLoop()
        /Users/zhbert/go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray_nonwindows.go:18 +0x1c fp=0x14000155f00 sp=0x14000155ee0 pc=0x10030d52c
github.com/getlantern/systray.Run(0x100674690, 0x100674680)
        /Users/zhbert/go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:78 +0x28 fp=0x14000155f20 sp=0x14000155f00 pc=0x10030caa8
main.startTrayApp()
        /Users/zhbert/Programming/gist-for-so-about-giu-and-systray/main.go:12 +0x2c fp=0x14000155f40 sp=0x14000155f20 pc=0x10030dbbc
main.main()
        /Users/zhbert/Programming/gist-for-so-about-giu-and-systray/main.go:54 +0x1c fp=0x14000155f50 sp=0x14000155f40 pc=0x10030e10c
runtime.main()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:267 +0x244 fp=0x14000155fd0 sp=0x14000155f50 pc=0x1001421d4
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 +0x4 fp=0x14000155fd0 sp=0x14000155fd0 pc=0x1001705d4

goroutine 2 [force gc (idle)]:
runtime.gopark(0x100674bb0, 0x1007c76c0, 0x11, 0x14, 0x1)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xe0 fp=0x14000044f70 sp=0x14000044f40 pc=0x100142630
runtime.goparkunlock(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:404 +0x34 fp=0x14000044fa0 sp=0x14000044f70 pc=0x1001426c4
runtime.forcegchelper()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:322 +0xb4 fp=0x14000044fd0 sp=0x14000044fa0 pc=0x100142454
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 +0x4 fp=0x14000044fd0 sp=0x14000044fd0 pc=0x1001705d4
created by runtime.init.6 in goroutine 1
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:310 +0x24

goroutine 18 [GC sweep wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x100674bb0, 0x1007c7b20, 0xc, 0x14, 0x1)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xe0 fp=0x14000040730 sp=0x14000040700 pc=0x100142630
runtime.goparkunlock(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:404 +0x34 fp=0x14000040760 sp=0x14000040730 pc=0x1001426c4
runtime.bgsweep(0x0?)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgcsweep.go:280 +0x9c fp=0x140000407b0 sp=0x14000040760 pc=0x10012d9fc
runtime.gcenable.func1()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x28 fp=0x140000407d0 sp=0x140000407b0 pc=0x100122a08
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 +0x4 fp=0x140000407d0 sp=0x140000407d0 pc=0x1001705d4
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgc.go:200 +0x6c

goroutine 19 [GC scavenge wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x100674bb0, 0x1007c7f40, 0xd, 0x14, 0x2)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xe0 fp=0x14000040f20 sp=0x14000040ef0 pc=0x100142630
runtime.goparkunlock(0x1400008e000?, 0x28?, 0xff?, 0x1?)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:404 +0x34 fp=0x14000040f50 sp=0x14000040f20 pc=0x1001426c4
runtime.(*scavengerState).park(0x1007c7f40)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:425 +0x4c fp=0x14000040f80 sp=0x14000040f50 pc=0x10012ae9c
runtime.bgscavenge(0x0?)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgcscavenge.go:653 +0x44 fp=0x14000040fb0 sp=0x14000040f80 pc=0x10012b3d4
runtime.gcenable.func2()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0x28 fp=0x14000040fd0 sp=0x14000040fb0 pc=0x1001229a8
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 +0x4 fp=0x14000040fd0 sp=0x14000040fd0 pc=0x1001705d4
created by runtime.gcenable in goroutine 1
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mgc.go:201 +0xac

goroutine 34 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.gopark(0x1006748f8, 0x10102fc60, 0x10, 0x14, 0x1)
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:398 +0xe0 fp=0x14000044580 sp=0x14000044550 pc=0x100142630
runtime.runfinq()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mfinal.go:193 +0xf0 fp=0x140000447d0 sp=0x14000044580 pc=0x100121bf0
runtime.goexit()
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:1197 +0x4 fp=0x140000447d0 sp=0x140000447d0 pc=0x1001705d4
created by runtime.createfing in goroutine 1
        /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.21.1/libexec/src/runtime/mfinal.go:163 +0x4c

r0      0x0
r1      0x0
r2      0x0
r3      0x0
r4      0x198464647
r5      0x170d05560
r6      0x6e
r7      0x3
r8      0xbd267fd56b3500a8
r9      0xbd267fd41be570a8
r10     0x200
r11     0xb
r12     0xb
r13     0x1ff800
r14     0x7fb
r15     0xa9a27020
r16     0x148
r17     0x1f80573f8
r18     0x0
r19     0x6
r20     0x170d07000
r21     0x1703
r22     0x170d070e0
r23     0x60000004ce60
r24     0x7
r25     0x1e7f2da90
r26     0x19b919710
r27     0xc8
r28     0x14000002ea0
r29     0x170d054d0
lr      0x1984a7c28
sp      0x170d054b0
pc      0x198470744
fault   0x198470744
Exiting.

Debugger finished with the exit code 0
```

I tried to call a window in a separate gorutin via `go`. And a lot more, but none of it helped.

Is it possible to solve this problem? And if so, how? I will be glad of any hints.